# ESPN iOS API with RESTKIT

Tags: ios, objective-c, api, restkit, espn

**EDIT- I recently posted a tutorial on Git on how to solve this question... Below is a link
https://github.com/lukejgeger/ESPN-API-Example.git**

I am playing with the ESPN API and am just trying to fill a tableview with all the teams in the NBA. I am using restkit and having some trouble.

Below is some code

```
RKURL *baseURL = [RKURL URLWithBaseURLString:@"http://api.espn.com"];

RKObjectManager *objectManager = [RKObjectManager objectManagerWithBaseURL:baseURL];
objectManager.client.baseURL = baseURL;

RKObjectMapping* taskMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Team class]];
[taskMapping mapKeyPath:@"name" toAttribute:@"teamName"];
[objectManager.mappingProvider setObjectMapping:taskMapping forResourcePathPattern:@"/teams"];
[objectManager loadObjectsAtResourcePath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/v1/sports/basketball/nba/teams?apikey=%@",kAPIKey] delegate:self];
[objectManager.mappingProvider setMapping:taskMapping forKeyPath:@"name"];
```

I get a response code 200 back, but I am getting the error

```
231 Encountered errors during mapping: Could not find an object mapping for keyPath
```

A full response of the JSON I am getting back for a team is below

```
{
    "sports": [
    {
        "name": "basketball",
        "id": 40,
        "leagues": [
        {
            "name": "National Basketball Assoc.",
            "abbreviation": "nba",
            "id": 46,
            "groupId": 7,
            "shortName": "NBA",
            "teams": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "location": "Atlanta",
                "name": "Hawks",
                "abbreviation": "ATL",
                "color": "002B5C",
                "links": {
                    "api": {
                        "teams": {
                            "href": "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/nba/teams/1"
                        },
                        "news": {
                            "href": "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/nba/teams/1/news"
                        },
                        "notes": {
                            "href": "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/nba/teams/1/news/notes"
                        }
                    },
                    "web": {
                        "teams": {
                            "href": "http://espn.go.com/nba/team/_/name/atl/atlanta-hawks?ex_cid=espnapi_public"
                        }
                    },
                    "mobile": {
                        "teams": {
                            "href": "http://m.espn.go.com/nba/clubhouse?teamId=1&ex_cid=espnapi_public"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "location": "Boston",
                "name": "Celtics",
                "abbreviation": "BOS",
                "color": "006532",
                "links": {
                    "api": {
                        "teams": {
                            "href": "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/nba/teams/2"
                        },
                        "news": {
                            "href": "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/nba/teams/2/news"
                        },
                        "notes": {
                            "href": "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/nba/teams/2/news/notes"
                        }
                    },
                    "web": {
                        "teams": {
                            "href": "http://espn.go.com/nba/team/_/name/bos/boston-celtics?ex_cid=espnapi_public"
                        }
                    },
                    "mobile": {
                        "teams": {
                            "href": "http://m.espn.go.com/nba/clubhouse?teamId=2&ex_cid=espnapi_public"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "location": "New Orleans",
                "name": "Hornets",
                "abbreviation": "NO",
                "color": "0093B1",
                "links": {
                    "api": {
                        "teams": {
                            "href": "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/nba/teams/3"
                        },
                        "news": {
                            "href": "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/nba/teams/3/news"
                        },
                        "notes": {
                            "href": "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/nba/teams/3/news/notes"
                        }
                    },
                    "web": {
                        "teams": {
                            "href": "http://espn.go.com/nba/team/_/name/no/new-orleans-hornets?ex_cid=espnapi_public"
                        }
                    },
                    "mobile": {
                        "teams": {
                            "href": "http://m.espn.go.com/nba/clubhouse?teamId=3&ex_cid=espnapi_public"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "location": "Chicago",
                "name": "Bulls",
                "abbreviation": "CHI",
                "color": "000000",
                "links": {
                    "api": {
                        "teams": {
                            "href": "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/nba/teams/4"
                        },
                        "news": {
                            "href": "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/nba/teams/4/news"
                        },
                        "notes": {
                            "href": "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/nba/teams/4/news/notes"
                        }
                    },
                    "web": {
                        "teams": {
                            "href": "http://espn.go.com/nba/team/_/name/chi/chicago-bulls?ex_cid=espnapi_public"
                        }
                    },
                    "mobile": {
                        "teams": {
                            "href": "http://m.espn.go.com/nba/clubhouse?teamId=4&ex_cid=espnapi_public"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 5,
                "location": "Cleveland",
                "name": "Cavaliers",
                "abbreviation": "CLE",
                "color": "061642",
                "links": {
                    "api": {
                        "teams": {
                            "href": "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/nba/teams/5"
                        },
                        "news": {
                            "href": "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/nba/teams/5/news"
                        },
                        "notes": {
                            "href": "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/nba/teams/5/news/notes"
                        }
                    },
                    "web": {
                        "teams": {
                            "href": "http://espn.go.com/nba/team/_/name/cle/cleveland-cavaliers?ex_cid=espnapi_public"
                        }
                    },
                    "mobile": {
                        "teams": {
                            "href": "http://m.espn.go.com/nba/clubhouse?teamId=5&ex_cid=espnapi_public"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 6,
                "location": "Dallas",
                "name": "Mavericks",
                "abbreviation": "DAL",
                "color": "0C479D",
                "links": {
                    "api": {
                        "teams": {
                            "href": "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/nba/teams/6"
                        },
                        "news": {
                            "href": "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/nba/teams/6/news"
                        },
                        "notes": {
                            "href": "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/nba/teams/6/news/notes"
                        }
                    },
                    "web": {
                        "teams": {
                            "href": "http://espn.go.com/nba/team/_/name/dal/dallas-mavericks?ex_cid=espnapi_public"
                        }
                    },
                    "mobile": {
                        "teams": {
                            "href": "http://m.espn.go.com/nba/clubhouse?teamId=6&ex_cid=espnapi_public"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 7,
                "location": "Denver",
                "name": "Nuggets",
                "abbreviation": "DEN",
                "color": "0860A8",
                "links": {
                    "api": {
                        "teams": {
                            "href": "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/nba/teams/7"
                        },
                        "news": {
                            "href": "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/nba/teams/7/news"
                        },
                        "notes": {
                            "href": "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/nba/teams/7/news/notes"
                        }
                    },
                    "web": {
                        "teams": {
                            "href": "http://espn.go.com/nba/team/_/name/den/denver-nuggets?ex_cid=espnapi_public"
                        }
                    },
                    "mobile": {
                        "teams": {
                            "href": "http://m.espn.go.com/nba/clubhouse?teamId=7&ex_cid=espnapi_public"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 8,
                "location": "Detroit",
                "name": "Pistons",
                "abbreviation": "DET",
                "color": "FA002C",
                "links": {
                    "api": {
                        "teams": {
                            "href": "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/nba/teams/8"
                        },
                        "news": {
                            "href": "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/nba/teams/8/news"
                        },
                        "notes": {
                            "href": "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/nba/teams/8/news/notes"
                        }
                    },
                    "web": {
                        "teams": {
                            "href": "http://espn.go.com/nba/team/_/name/det/detroit-pistons?ex_cid=espnapi_public"
                        }
                    },
                    "mobile": {
                        "teams": {
                            "href": "http://m.espn.go.com/nba/clubhouse?teamId=8&ex_cid=espnapi_public"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 9,
                "location": "Golden State",
                "name": "Warriors",
                "abbreviation": "GS",
                "color": "00275D",
                "links": {
                    "api": {
                        "teams": {
                            "href": "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/nba/teams/9"
                        },
                        "news": {
                            "href": "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/nba/teams/9/news"
                        },
                        "notes": {
                            "href": "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/nba/teams/9/news/notes"
                        }
                    },
                    "web": {
                        "teams": {
                            "href": "http://espn.go.com/nba/team/_/name/gs/golden-state-warriors?ex_cid=espnapi_public"
                        }
                    },
                    "mobile": {
                        "teams": {
                            "href": "http://m.espn.go.com/nba/clubhouse?teamId=9&ex_cid=espnapi_public"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 10,
                "location": "Houston",
                "name": "Rockets",
                "abbreviation": "HOU",
                "color": "D40026",
                "links": {
                    "api": {
                        "teams": {
                            "href": "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/nba/teams/10"
                        },
                        "news": {
                            "href": "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/nba/teams/10/news"
                        },
                        "notes": {
                            "href": "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/nba/teams/10/news/notes"
                        }
                    },
                    "web": {
                        "teams": {
                            "href": "http://espn.go.com/nba/team/_/name/hou/houston-rockets?ex_cid=espnapi_public"
                        }
                    },
                    "mobile": {
                        "teams": {
                            "href": "http://m.espn.go.com/nba/clubhouse?teamId=10&ex_cid=espnapi_public"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 11,
                "location": "Indiana",
                "name": "Pacers",
                "abbreviation": "IND",
                "color": "061642",
                "links": {
                    "api": {
                        "teams": {
                            "href": "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/nba/teams/11"
                        },
                        "news": {
                            "href": "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/nba/teams/11/news"
                        },
                        "notes": {
                            "href": "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/nba/teams/11/news/notes"
                        }
                    },
                    "web": {
                        "teams": {
                            "href": "http://espn.go.com/nba/team/_/name/ind/indiana-pacers?ex_cid=espnapi_public"
                        }
                    },
                    "mobile": {
                        "teams": {
                            "href": "http://m.espn.go.com/nba/clubhouse?teamId=11&ex_cid=espnapi_public"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 12,
                "location": "Los Angeles",
                "name": "Clippers",
                "abbreviation": "LAC",
                "color": "FA0028",
                "links": {
                    "api": {
                        "teams": {
                            "href": "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/nba/teams/12"
                        },
                        "news": {
                            "href": "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/nba/teams/12/news"
                        },
                        "notes": {
                            "href": "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/nba/teams/12/news/notes"
                        }
                    },
                    "web": {
                        "teams": {
                            "href": "http://espn.go.com/nba/team/_/name/lac/los-angeles-clippers?ex_cid=espnapi_public"
                        }
                    },
                    "mobile": {
                        "teams": {
                            "href": "http://m.espn.go.com/nba/clubhouse?teamId=12&ex_cid=espnapi_public"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 13,
                "location": "Los Angeles",
                "name": "Lakers",
                "abbreviation": "LAL",
                "color": "542582",
                "links": {
                    "api": {
                        "teams": {
                            "href": "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/nba/teams/13"
                        },
                        "news": {
                            "href": "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/nba/teams/13/news"
                        },
                        "notes": {
                            "href": "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/nba/teams/13/news/notes"
                        }
                    },
                    "web": {
                        "teams": {
                            "href": "http://espn.go.com/nba/team/_/name/lal/los-angeles-lakers?ex_cid=espnapi_public"
                        }
                    },
                    "mobile": {
                        "teams": {
                            "href": "http://m.espn.go.com/nba/clubhouse?teamId=13&ex_cid=espnapi_public"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 14,
                "location": "Miami",
                "name": "Heat",
                "abbreviation": "MIA",
                "color": "000000",
                "links": {
                    "api": {
                        "teams": {
                            "href": "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/nba/teams/14"
                        },
                        "news": {
                            "href": "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/nba/teams/14/news"
                        },
                        "notes": {
                            "href": "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/nba/teams/14/news/notes"
                        }
                    },
                    "web": {
                        "teams": {
                            "href": "http://espn.go.com/nba/team/_/name/mia/miami-heat?ex_cid=espnapi_public"
                        }
                    },
                    "mobile": {
                        "teams": {
                            "href": "http://m.espn.go.com/nba/clubhouse?teamId=14&ex_cid=espnapi_public"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 15,
                "location": "Milwaukee",
                "name": "Bucks",
                "abbreviation": "MIL",
                "color": "003813",
                "links": {
                    "api": {
                        "teams": {
                            "href": "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/nba/teams/15"
                        },
                        "news": {
                            "href": "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/nba/teams/15/news"
                        },
                        "notes": {
                            "href": "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/nba/teams/15/news/notes"
                        }
                    },
                    "web": {
                        "teams": {
                            "href": "http://espn.go.com/nba/team/_/name/mil/milwaukee-bucks?ex_cid=espnapi_public"
                        }
                    },
                    "mobile": {
                        "teams": {
                            "href": "http://m.espn.go.com/nba/clubhouse?teamId=15&ex_cid=espnapi_public"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 16,
                "location": "Minnesota",
                "name": "Timberwolves",
                "abbreviation": "MIN",
                "color": "0E3764",
                "links": {
                    "api": {
                        "teams": {
                            "href": "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/nba/teams/16"
                        },
                        "news": {
                            "href": "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/nba/teams/16/news"
                        },
                        "notes": {
                            "href": "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/nba/teams/16/news/notes"
                        }
                    },
                    "web": {
                        "teams": {
                            "href": "http://espn.go.com/nba/team/_/name/min/minnesota-timberwolves?ex_cid=espnapi_public"
                        }
                    },
                    "mobile": {
                        "teams": {
                            "href": "http://m.espn.go.com/nba/clubhouse?teamId=16&ex_cid=espnapi_public"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 17,
                "location": "Brooklyn",
                "name": "Nets",
                "abbreviation": "BKN",
                "color": "06143F",
                "links": {
                    "api": {
                        "teams": {
                            "href": "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/nba/teams/17"
                        },
                        "news": {
                            "href": "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/nba/teams/17/news"
                        },
                        "notes": {
                            "href": "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/nba/teams/17/news/notes"
                        }
                    },
                    "web": {
                        "teams": {
                            "href": "http://espn.go.com/nba/team/_/name/bkn/brooklyn-nets?ex_cid=espnapi_public"
                        }
                    },
                    "mobile": {
                        "teams": {
                            "href": "http://m.espn.go.com/nba/clubhouse?teamId=17&ex_cid=espnapi_public"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 18,
                "location": "New York",
                "name": "Knicks",
                "abbreviation": "NY",
                "color": "225EA8",
                "links": {
                    "api": {
                        "teams": {
                            "href": "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/nba/teams/18"
                        },
                        "news": {
                            "href": "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/nba/teams/18/news"
                        },
                        "notes": {
                            "href": "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/nba/teams/18/news/notes"
                        }
                    },
                    "web": {
                        "teams": {
                            "href": "http://espn.go.com/nba/team/_/name/ny/new-york-knicks?ex_cid=espnapi_public"
                        }
                    },
                    "mobile": {
                        "teams": {
                            "href": "http://m.espn.go.com/nba/clubhouse?teamId=18&ex_cid=espnapi_public"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 19,
                "location": "Orlando",
                "name": "Magic",
                "abbreviation": "ORL",
                "color": "0860A8",
                "links": {
                    "api": {
                        "teams": {
                            "href": "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/nba/teams/19"
                        },
                        "news": {
                            "href": "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/nba/teams/19/news"
                        },
                        "notes": {
                            "href": "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/nba/teams/19/news/notes"
                        }
                    },
                    "web": {
                        "teams": {
                            "href": "http://espn.go.com/nba/team/_/name/orl/orlando-magic?ex_cid=espnapi_public"
                        }
                    },
                    "mobile": {
                        "teams": {
                            "href": "http://m.espn.go.com/nba/clubhouse?teamId=19&ex_cid=espnapi_public"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 20,
                "location": "Philadelphia",
                "name": "76ers",
                "abbreviation": "PHI",
                "color": "000000",
                "links": {
                    "api": {
                        "teams": {
                            "href": "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/nba/teams/20"
                        },
                        "news": {
                            "href": "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/nba/teams/20/news"
                        },
                        "notes": {
                            "href": "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/nba/teams/20/news/notes"
                        }
                    },
                    "web": {
                        "teams": {
                            "href": "http://espn.go.com/nba/team/_/name/phi/philadelphia-76ers?ex_cid=espnapi_public"
                        }
                    },
                    "mobile": {
                        "teams": {
                            "href": "http://m.espn.go.com/nba/clubhouse?teamId=20&ex_cid=espnapi_public"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 21,
                "location": "Phoenix",
                "name": "Suns",
                "abbreviation": "PHX",
                "color": "23006A",
                "links": {
                    "api": {
                        "teams": {
                            "href": "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/nba/teams/21"
                        },
                        "news": {
                            "href": "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/nba/teams/21/news"
                        },
                        "notes": {
                            "href": "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/nba/teams/21/news/notes"
                        }
                    },
                    "web": {
                        "teams": {
                            "href": "http://espn.go.com/nba/team/_/name/phx/phoenix-suns?ex_cid=espnapi_public"
                        }
                    },
                    "mobile": {
                        "teams": {
                            "href": "http://m.espn.go.com/nba/clubhouse?teamId=21&ex_cid=espnapi_public"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 22,
                "location": "Portland",
                "name": "Trail Blazers",
                "abbreviation": "POR",
                "color": "000000",
                "links": {
                    "api": {
                        "teams": {
                            "href": "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/nba/teams/22"
                        },
                        "news": {
                            "href": "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/nba/teams/22/news"
                        },
                        "notes": {
                            "href": "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/nba/teams/22/news/notes"
                        }
                    },
                    "web": {
                        "teams": {
                            "href": "http://espn.go.com/nba/team/_/name/por/portland-trail-blazers?ex_cid=espnapi_public"
                        }
                    },
                    "mobile": {
                        "teams": {
                            "href": "http://m.espn.go.com/nba/clubhouse?teamId=22&ex_cid=espnapi_public"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 23,
                "location": "Sacramento",
                "name": "Kings",
                "abbreviation": "SAC",
                "color": "393996",
                "links": {
                    "api": {
                        "teams": {
                            "href": "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/nba/teams/23"
                        },
                        "news": {
                            "href": "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/nba/teams/23/news"
                        },
                        "notes": {
                            "href": "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/nba/teams/23/news/notes"
                        }
                    },
                    "web": {
                        "teams": {
                            "href": "http://espn.go.com/nba/team/_/name/sac/sacramento-kings?ex_cid=espnapi_public"
                        }
                    },
                    "mobile": {
                        "teams": {
                            "href": "http://m.espn.go.com/nba/clubhouse?teamId=23&ex_cid=espnapi_public"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 24,
                "location": "San Antonio",
                "name": "Spurs",
                "abbreviation": "SA",
                "color": "000000",
                "links": {
                    "api": {
                        "teams": {
                            "href": "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/nba/teams/24"
                        },
                        "news": {
                            "href": "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/nba/teams/24/news"
                        },
                        "notes": {
                            "href": "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/nba/teams/24/news/notes"
                        }
                    },
                    "web": {
                        "teams": {
                            "href": "http://espn.go.com/nba/team/_/name/sa/san-antonio-spurs?ex_cid=espnapi_public"
                        }
                    },
                    "mobile": {
                        "teams": {
                            "href": "http://m.espn.go.com/nba/clubhouse?teamId=24&ex_cid=espnapi_public"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 25,
                "location": "Oklahoma City",
                "name": "Thunder",
                "abbreviation": "OKC",
                "color": "C67C03",
                "links": {
                    "api": {
                        "teams": {
                            "href": "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/nba/teams/25"
                        },
                        "news": {
                            "href": "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/nba/teams/25/news"
                        },
                        "notes": {
                            "href": "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/nba/teams/25/news/notes"
                        }
                    },
                    "web": {
                        "teams": {
                            "href": "http://espn.go.com/nba/team/_/name/okc/oklahoma-city-thunder?ex_cid=espnapi_public"
                        }
                    },
                    "mobile": {
                        "teams": {
                            "href": "http://m.espn.go.com/nba/clubhouse?teamId=25&ex_cid=espnapi_public"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 26,
                "location": "Utah",
                "name": "Jazz",
                "abbreviation": "UTAH",
                "color": "06143F",
                "links": {
                    "api": {
                        "teams": {
                            "href": "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/nba/teams/26"
                        },
                        "news": {
                            "href": "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/nba/teams/26/news"
                        },
                        "notes": {
                            "href": "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/nba/teams/26/news/notes"
                        }
                    },
                    "web": {
                        "teams": {
                            "href": "http://espn.go.com/nba/team/_/name/utah/utah-jazz?ex_cid=espnapi_public"
                        }
                    },
                    "mobile": {
                        "teams": {
                            "href": "http://m.espn.go.com/nba/clubhouse?teamId=26&ex_cid=espnapi_public"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 27,
                "location": "Washington",
                "name": "Wizards",
                "abbreviation": "WSH",
                "color": "0E3764",
                "links": {
                    "api": {
                        "teams": {
                            "href": "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/nba/teams/27"
                        },
                        "news": {
                            "href": "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/nba/teams/27/news"
                        },
                        "notes": {
                            "href": "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/nba/teams/27/news/notes"
                        }
                    },
                    "web": {
                        "teams": {
                            "href": "http://espn.go.com/nba/team/_/name/wsh/washington-wizards?ex_cid=espnapi_public"
                        }
                    },
                    "mobile": {
                        "teams": {
                            "href": "http://m.espn.go.com/nba/clubhouse?teamId=27&ex_cid=espnapi_public"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 28,
                "location": "Toronto",
                "name": "Raptors",
                "abbreviation": "TOR",
                "color": "CE0F41",
                "links": {
                    "api": {
                        "teams": {
                            "href": "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/nba/teams/28"
                        },
                        "news": {
                            "href": "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/nba/teams/28/news"
                        },
                        "notes": {
                            "href": "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/nba/teams/28/news/notes"
                        }
                    },
                    "web": {
                        "teams": {
                            "href": "http://espn.go.com/nba/team/_/name/tor/toronto-raptors?ex_cid=espnapi_public"
                        }
                    },
                    "mobile": {
                        "teams": {
                            "href": "http://m.espn.go.com/nba/clubhouse?teamId=28&ex_cid=espnapi_public"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 29,
                "location": "Memphis",
                "name": "Grizzlies",
                "abbreviation": "MEM",
                "color": "5D76A8",
                "links": {
                    "api": {
                        "teams": {
                            "href": "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/nba/teams/29"
                        },
                        "news": {
                            "href": "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/nba/teams/29/news"
                        },
                        "notes": {
                            "href": "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/nba/teams/29/news/notes"
                        }
                    },
                    "web": {
                        "teams": {
                            "href": "http://espn.go.com/nba/team/_/name/mem/memphis-grizzlies?ex_cid=espnapi_public"
                        }
                    },
                    "mobile": {
                        "teams": {
                            "href": "http://m.espn.go.com/nba/clubhouse?teamId=29&ex_cid=espnapi_public"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 30,
                "location": "Charlotte",
                "name": "Bobcats",
                "abbreviation": "CHA",
                "color": "FE3310",
                "links": {
                    "api": {
                        "teams": {
                            "href": "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/nba/teams/30"
                        },
                        "news": {
                            "href": "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/nba/teams/30/news"
                        },
                        "notes": {
                            "href": "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/nba/teams/30/news/notes"
                        }
                    },
                    "web": {
                        "teams": {
                            "href": "http://espn.go.com/nba/team/_/name/cha/charlotte-bobcats?ex_cid=espnapi_public"
                        }
                    },
                    "mobile": {
                        "teams": {
                            "href": "http://m.espn.go.com/nba/clubhouse?teamId=30&ex_cid=espnapi_public"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }]
        }]
    }],
    "resultsOffset": 0,
    "resultsLimit": 50,
    "resultsCount": 30,
    "timestamp": "2012-11-05T00:40:18Z",
    "status": "success"
}
```

Comment: Is that the full response? It's not valid JSON.

Comment: no check the edit for full response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a tutorial on how to use ESPN-API with iOS

https://github.com/lukejgeger/ESPN-API-Example.git

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```
[objectManager.mappingProvider setMapping:taskMapping forKeyPath:@"name"];
```

since taskMapping maps "name" to "teamName", assigning that mapping for the keyPath "name" will result in the following search: "name.name" which is obviously not what you want. The rest of the code appears to be correct, I would just remove that line and you should be alright.

Comment: Hey thanks for your response, I deleted that line but I am still getting   Adding mapping error: Could not find an object mapping for keyPath: '' and Encountered errors during mapping: Could not find an object mapping for keyPath: ''